# Script doesn't work with img

Tags: javascript

Why doesn't it work? I want to click on next.jpg and see, that 2.png disappear and 1.png appear.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function next(id) 
{ 
    var callend = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
    callend.display = 'none'; 
    id++; 
    var callend2 = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
    callend2.display = 'inline'; 
    } 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<img src="next.jpg" onclick="next(1)" > 

<img id="c1" border="0" style="display: inline" src="2.png" usemap="#map2"> 
<img id ="c2" border="0" style="display: none" src="1.png" usemap="#map1"> 

........
```

**EDIT** : If you indented your code, you would see the error

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end of your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove extra } and check , it is working fine

```
function next(id) {

var callend = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
callend.display = 'none'; 
id++; 
var callend2 = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
callend2.display = 'inline'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function next(id) 
{ 
var callend = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
callend.display = 'none'; 
id++; 
var callend2 = document.getElementById('c' + id).style; 
callend2.display = 'inline'; 
}
```

extra **}** curly braces you are using at end of the function remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a suuperfluous `}` at the end of your script. made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5Um6/)